# COUNT() the number of MAX() occurrences in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a donation database and one of the reports I run against it I would like to include the number of donations that equal the months maximum donation. For example the months highest donation may be $100, but there may be 5 people who all donated $100, I would like to get that count.

My current query is:

```
SELECT SUM(mc_gross) AS Donations,
       SUM(mc_fee) AS Fees,
       COUNT(payment_date) AS DontationCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT payer_email) AS DonatorCount,
       MAX(mc_gross) AS MaxDonation,
       @MaxD:=MAX(mc_gross),
       (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM #__paypal_donations
            WHERE MONTH(payment_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
            AND YEAR(payment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
            AND mc_gross = @MaxD
       ) as MaxDonationMultiplier,
       AVG(mc_gross) AS AverageDonation
FROM #__paypal_donations
 WHERE MONTH(payment_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(payment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

So I think I may be close, but it looks like either the value I am storing in @MaxD for use in my subquery is not working or the comparison itself in mc_gross = @MaxD is not working because if I replace @MaxD with a real value I get a proper count.

Comment: you can do it with a nested query something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__paypal_donations WHERE mc_gross = (SELECT MAX(mc_gross) FROM #__paypal_donations)`

Comment: Thanks @bansi, that worked. Didn't think I would need to do a nested nested query that deep just to do what seems like a simple task, but whatever gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot depend on the order of assignment of expressions in MySQL.  That makes a query such as yours quite dangerous.  Fortunately, you can easily solve this problem with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(mc_gross) AS Donations, SUM(mc_fee) AS Fees, COUNT(payment_date) AS DontationCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT payer_email) AS DonatorCount, MAX(mc_gross) AS MaxDonation,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM #__paypal_donations pd2
        WHERE MONTH(pd2payment_date) =  MONTH(pd.payment_date)) AND
              YEAR(pd2payment_date) = YEAR(pd.payment_date) AND
              pd2.mc_gross = MAX(mc_gross)
       ) as MaxDonationMultiplier,
       AVG(mc_gross) AS AverageDonation
FROM #__paypal_donations pd
WHERE MONTH(payment_date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND
      YEAR(payment_date) = YEAR(CURDATE());
```